# Hide Singular Span

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using

```
span.ui.mini.teal.label {
    display: none !important;
}
```

renders all Span elements hidden.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVDhV.png)

Need to hide only Span elements Amount & Interest.

Tried

```
span.ui.mini.teal.label-amount {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute selector in square brackets after the tag as shown below

```css
span[title="Amount"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<span>Amount1</span>
<span title="Amount">Amount2</span>
<span>Amount3</span>
```

Comment: I bow at the sheer simplicity of it! Thank You